# font size depending on number of words

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have vertically aligned *div* with *fixed height* (800px). The problem is that my div is dynamic and *font size* depends on number of words, for example
[image]

how can I achieve that?

[link](https://fiddle.jshell.net/elene/640kLut2/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should take a look at [Flowtype](http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/), a JS Library for dynamically resizing your text.

Comment: Or http://fittextjs.com/ may be?